# Why is my javascript file running before the components have finished?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

so i have a react website. I have a script file for animations/transitions called AppHomeScript.js that I import in the index.html with a script tag at the end:

```
 <script src="./scripts/AppHomeScript.js" defer ></script>
```

```
the script file also has :
window.onload = () => { 
    console.log("LOADING SCRIPTS");
    const homeButton = document.querySelector(".home-btn");
    console.log("HOME BTN: ", homeButton);
    const loginPage = document.querySelector(".login-page");
    const loginButton = document.querySelector(".login-btn");
    const registerButton = document.querySelector(".register-btn");
    const registerPage = document.querySelector(".register-page")
    const mainTexts = document.querySelector(".main-texts");
    
    const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");

})
```

to make sure that it only runs after the components have finished loading. The problem is, in my local computer. the animations work fine in my chrome and operaGX browser. but it does not work on my
internet explorer,chrome's incognito mode, and my android phone's chrome. I also already hosted it in netlify, and I asked my friend if the animations work on their browser, but it does not. a part of the file console logs one of the documents it is trying to get, and it logs null. this gives me the idea that the script is being run even though the components haven't finished rendering.

I am using ES6 for the scripts, if you want to see the whole Script file, it is here:
https://github.com/BjornPython/locate-martial-arts-client/blob/main/public/scripts/AppHomeScript.js

here is the live demo of the app hosted in netlify:

https://poetic-capybara-66732c.netlify.app/

i tried different ways of importing the script file. like using useEffect and ComponentDidMount, or removing the

```
window.onload = () => {}
```

when i remove window.onload, the script runs before the components run, and it does not work on any of the browsers.

EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT // EDIT

I found a fix, but i'm not sure if this is the best way to deal with this problem.

I added a setTimeout function inside my window.onload.

```
window.onload = () => {

setTimeout(() => {
         
        // MY CODE HERE // MY CODE HERE
    
    }, 500);
}
```

If you have a better way of solving this problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: 1. Are the elements inside the React root? It's not a good idea to manually use addEventListener or manipulate their classList directly. 2. If you want something to run right after an element is appended somewhere in the document, try using DOM mutation observer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why your JavaScript code may be running before your components have finished rendering in React:

1. Execution order: JavaScript code is executed in the order it is included in your HTML file. If your JavaScript code is included before your React components, it will execute before the components can render.
2. Asynchronous rendering: React components can be rendered asynchronously, which means that the component may not finish rendering before the JavaScript code runs. This can happen if your component makes an API call or performs other asynchronous operations.
3. State updates: React components can also update their state asynchronously, which means that changes to the state may not be reflected in the component before your JavaScript code runs.

To ensure that your JavaScript code runs after your React components have finished rendering, you can use the componentDidMount lifecycle method. This method is called after the component has finished rendering, so you can be sure that your component is ready before running any JavaScript code. Alternatively, you can use React's built-in useEffect hook to run code after the component has finished rendering.

Comment: i have already tried those. and no offense, are a bot because you sound just like chatGPT when i asked it this question. if not, thank you for taking the time to answer, i appreciate it very much.